# Rotated text using Courier font not displayed in Opera

Tags: css, fonts, opera, css-transforms

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class='box'>text</div>​
```

and CSS:

```
.box {
    /* non-essential */
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2em;
    background: plum;

    /* ESSENTIAL */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    font-family: Courier;
}​
```

And this is [**the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/MabJd/). I've omitted the prefixes here, but they are in the fiddle.

Expected result:

[image: expected result]

It is also the result I get in Chrome, Firefox, IE9, Safari.

However, in Opera it looks like this:

[image: opera result]

- If I take out the transform (that is, the div is not rotated
  anymore), then the text is shown.
- If I replace the font with another one, then the text is shown.

So **why is this happening** and **what other solutions do I have**?

In case this helps:

[image: about opera]

Comment: not an answer, just FYI - on Mac it works perfectly in Opera

Comment: Have you tried using a vendor specific prefix to see if that helps?  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);

Comment: @BillyMoat Yes, she did - have you seen the fiddle?

Comment: @ZoltanToth - Ah, only looked at the code posted here - my bad.

Comment: Maybe during the transformation the text becomes too slim to be visible. Have you try to increase the font-size or with a different angle ?

Comment: My theory is, Opera do support a (.fon) font type, and this font type might not have the functionality to display the text with transform property (confirm it with .fon extension, e.g “Roman”). If we verify the font face on Chrome, it was rendered in “Courier New”/fallback font and not the Courier(Courier Regular – verify this on your OS font list).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Why is this happening

It's happening because Opera has resolved *Courier* to `courier.fon` a bit-mapped font, and Opera has not implemented rotation for bit-mapped fonts.

You get the same results with *Modern* and *Roman* and any other font where you have a `.fon` version.

You can look in `C:\Windows\Fonts` for a complete list.

#### What other solutions do I have

If you are relying on the exact metrics of the font when it is presented on the page, you may want to consider using a web font.

If calling the font "courier" is important, then you could ignore opera: It's not very popular, this is a bit of an obscure bug, and since [Opera is ditching Presto for Webkit](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/300-million-users-and-move-to-webkit), it simply involves waiting.

Answer (score -1):

If you change the font-family tag to the below it works:

```
font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3tTyp/1/

Comment: I know it works, I mentioned that in the question. It works if I use monospace, Courier New, Arial, Helvetica... but not Courier. I was asking for a way that does not involve removing the transform or changing the font-family.

Comment: Apologies, I'm evidently not paying enough attention today :(